# How to specify Update the instance configuration setting in terraform Managed Instance Group module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using Terrafrom Managed Instance Group template to create Managed Instance Group. This is how the MIG configuration looks like:

```
module "mig" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/mig"
  version = "8.0.0"

  project_id        = var.project_id
  target_size       = var.target_number_of_instance
  hostname          = "mig-sample"
  instance_template = module.instance_template.self_link
  region            = var.region_name
  named_ports = [
    {
      name = "http",
      port = 8000
    }
  ]
  # update_policy = [{
  #   type                           = "PROACTIVE"
  #   instance_redistribution_type   = "PROACTIVE"
  #   minimal_action                 = "REPLACE"
  #   most_disruptive_allowed_action = "REPLACE"
  #   max_surge_fixed                = 0
  #   max_surge_percent              = null
  #   max_unavailable_percent        = null
  #   max_unavailable_fixed          = 4
  #   min_ready_sec                  = 50
  #   replacement_method             = "RECREATE"
  # }]


}
```

On GCP console, one of the option in Managed Instance Group is to specify VM instance lifecycle which has 2 options:

1. Keep the same instance configuration
2. Update the instance configuration

When I deploy my Terraform template, it always selects option 1 (Keep the same instance configuration).

How do I tell Terraform Managed Instance Group template to select option 2 (Update the instance configuration)

I tried specifying `update_policy` attribute but that did not work. You can see the `update_policy` config in the commented section.